# Text not appearing in TextView boxes after inflate()

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am attempting to create a dashboard that contains a textview for each message in a users queue upon login.  Since the view for this will have to be dynamically built, I am inflating a layout for each number of messages in the queue; The layout has only a linearlayout with three textview elements that will change depending on the contents of each message (Sender, message, time, etc...). After inflating the layout, there is not any text within the inflated view only a container of white space.  I have tried changing the inflate method to call null as the second parameter, as well as, omitting the third parameter to force default (true) to no avail.  Thanks in advance for your help.

From activity_dash_board.java

```
public class DashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        // Create Async object for network processing
        DashBoardAsync m_processDashboard = new DashBoardAsync(getApplicationContext(), (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL_dashboardContainer), (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL_pagingQueue));

        // Get the info passed from the LoginActivity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


     }
```

From DashBoardAsync.java

```
public class DashBoardAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

            public static String[][] m_organizationPagingQueue = new String[3][3];

            private LinearLayout m_LL_container;
            private LinearLayout m_LL_queue;
            private Context m_C_context;


            public DashBoardAsync(Context context, LinearLayout container, LinearLayout queue){
                m_C_context = context;
                m_LL_container = container;
                m_LL_queue = queue;
            }

//doInBackground omitted

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)m_C_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

for(int a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dash_board_paging_queue, m_LL_container, false);

    TextView requester = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.TV_pagingRequester);
    requester.setText("This is some text");

    TextView message = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.TV_pagingMessage);
    message.setText("This is some text");


    m_LL_container.addView(inflatedView);
}
super.onPostExecute(result);

}
```

From activity_dash_board_paging_queue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/LL_pagingQueue"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:showDividers="end"
    android:divider="#a41515">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/TV_pagingRequester"
        android:id="@+id/TV_pagingRequester" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/TV_pagingMessage"
        android:id="@+id/TV_pagingMessage" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/TV_pagingTime"
        android:id="@+id/TV_pagingTime"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

From activity_dash_board.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/LL_dashboardContainer"
        android:background="#24e3b0">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="Scrolling header" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Layout with inflated View containing blank textviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6anZ.png)

[Preview of activity_dash_board_paging_queue.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHiN2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your view isn't fully created when the `postExecute` runs. I would move that async call to the `onResume` where you know the UI exists.

Also, don't use `getApplicationContext()`, use `this`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately that did not resolve the issue.  I added the onResume method inside of my activity and moved the initialization of the DashBoardAsync object and the call to the execute method inside of it but it still displays empty whitespace

Comment: @xec86 Try changing the context to `this` rather than `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: The context shouldn't matter. It is only needed to get the LayoutInflater

Comment: @CoryRoy Success! it was not handing off the context as 'this'.  Looks great now.  Thanks